# SQL Server index for JSON array of objects

Tags: json, sql-server, indexing

I got a table `db_elements` with two columns. Id (primary key of type `binary(255)`) and event (JSON content of type `nvarchar(max)`). Example content for the event column would be a JSON in the following format:

```json
{
    "id": 123,
    "name": "test",
    "elements": [{
        "element_id": 45,
        "element_type": "type_01"
    }, {
        "element_id": 65,
        "element_type": "type_01"
    }, {
        "element_id": 87,
        "element_type": "type_02"
    }]
}
```

The number of elements in the JSON array 'elements' varies from row to row, but the format of the objects inside is always the same, although I simplified the JSON for the question here.
Now I want to query the table by using a query like this:

```sql
SELECT id, event FROM db_elements 
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(event, '$.elements') WITH (
    element_id int '$.element_id', 
    element_type nvarchar(max) '$.element_type'
) WHERE element_id = 87 AND element_type = 'type_02';
```

The query itself works just fine, but I want to create an index to accelerate the execution because in my use case the number of entries in the table is already quite large and will grow even more over time. I could only find examples of indexes for simple fields like the 'name' field in the docs and on stack overflow and if have no idea how to tackle this problem.

So my question are:

- Is there a way to create an index for the JSON array in order to accelerate the execution of my query?
- If yes, how?
- If no, is there a workaround for this problem?

Comment: If you want to index your data, normalise it.

Comment: you could create a side table which has pre-shredded json that you could index. Alternatively, you could perhaps change to xml and use xml indexes, but i personally haven't found them to be more performant in my previous attempts

Comment: @ThomA I cant change the format of the event data, because we use the db as a 'schemaless' sink for serialized Apache Kafka events.

Comment: @siggemannen Im not quite sure what you mean with side table. Do you mean extracting all the json array elements and putting them into separate columns to index them?

Comment: Separate table, not columns

Comment: I know, i meant that the separate table has a column for each json array element in order to index it.

Comment: No, i would probably use a row based approach. Each array element = new row

Comment: you could also move this stuff out of SQL Server entirely, other document based system like elasticsearch might provide better performance

Comment: Ooohh, now i get it. That would solve the problem. Im going to try that. Thanks a lot! A document based system would be even better, but we are restricted by the customers preferences to use a SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a computed column using a schema-bound scalar function, then index that.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.IsMyJson(@json nvarchar(max))
RETURNS bit
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS BEGIN
  RETURN CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.elements')
      WITH (
        element_id int '$.element_id', 
        element_type nvarchar(max) '$.element_type'
      )
      WHERE element_id = 87
        AND element_type = 'type_02'
  ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
END;
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE db_elements (
  id int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  event nvarchar(max),
  is_my_Json AS dbo.IsMyJson(event),
  INDEX IX NONCLUSTERED (is_my_Json, id) INCLUDE (event)
)
```

Then you just query the computed column, and the index will be used.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM db_elements
WHERE is_my_Json = 1;
```

You could also change the function to return the actual data, although in that case you cannot index `nvarchar(max)` as it's too big (you would need to cast it shorter).

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/EL_H5GBm)